# How to get the current photo id in fotorama with php?

Tags: fotorama

How can I get the current photo id in fotorama? I'd want to get the number of the photo showed before the thumbs slideshow and get it with php, but I don't know how to get that photo id. I've been trying with the onClick function but I don't know the number of the inner ID in the jscript. 
Thank you very much to anyone who could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```
$('#your-fotorama-id')
  .on('fotorama:show', function (e, fotorama) {
    // show the current index
    alert(fotorama.activeIndex);

    // or the id
    alert(fotorama.activeFrame.id);
  });
```

Comment: I've put the code at the end of the fotorama.js file. As within the drupal page I've named the div class as "fotorama" I think my fotorama-id is simply "fotorama". Is this correct? Maybe I'm doing something wrong, because as I'm changing the photos no alert is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fotorama.activeIndex to get the integer based index for current active image. Try this:

```
alert(fotorama.activeIndex);
```